# Angular URL rewrite not happening

Tags: angularjs, angular2-routing

I have an application hosted at localhost:4200. After getting the list when edit is clicked page navigation is happening but the URL is not rewriting.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'employee', component: EmployeeListComponent },
  { path: 'employee/add', component: EmployeeAddComponent },
  { path: 'employee/edit', component: EmployeeEditComponent },
  { path: 'customer', component: CustomerListComponent },
  { path: 'ap', component: PayablesComponent },
  { path: 'ar', component: ReceivablesComponent }
])
```

Home Page
[image]

Edit Page
[image]

The URL is same for the both the pages.

Rewrite component snippet,

```
  <td>
    <a [routerLink]="['/employee/edit']"><i class="fa fa-pencil ky-teal-text"></i> </a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a><i class="fa fa-close ky-red-text"></i> </a>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were errors in the component hence angular was falling back to the previous successful route without rerouting. Upon fixing the errors in the component the rewrite was happening fine. Thanks and the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a relative path and see,

```
  <a [routerLink]="['./employee/edit']"><i class="fa fa-pencil ky-teal-text"></i> </a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

Comment: This is throwing unexpected token error. RouterLinkActive is for making as the active route right but not fpr navigation?

Comment: @Sekar yes i misunderstood the question, just try with ./